# While loop using realloc, won't update arrays when printing

Tags: c, memory-management

The code will not produce a compiler error, but i am trying to update the memory allocation after every loop if the user types `Y`, and increase the size of the memory. But after the first while loop, when i try to print the list of numbers using the first for loop, it will just show one number which will be `0.00000`. I can't get it to update (which is what I am trying to do in the second if loop). Any help is appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    double *userNum = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double));
    double sum = 0;
    char userChar = 'Y';
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    if (userNum == NULL) {
            printf("Error with memory");

            return 1;
    }

    while (userChar == 'Y' || userChar == 'y') {

            printf("Enter a number\n");
            scanf("%lf", userNum);

            printf("List of numbers:\n");
            for (j; j < (i + 1); j++) {
                    printf( "%lf\n", userNum[j]);
            }

            printf("More numbers (Y/N)? \n");
            getchar();
            scanf("%c", &userChar);


            if (userChar == 'Y' || userChar == 'y') {
                    userNum = realloc(userNum, (i + 2) * sizeof(double));
                    i++;
            }
    }

    return 0;
)
```

Comment: It might helps `scanf("%c", &userChar);` --> `scanf(" %c", &userChar);` give whitespace before `%c`.

Comment: You need to reinitialize `j` to zero at the beginning of the output loop.

Comment: This `scanf("%lf", userNum);` always scans into the arrays 1st (index 0) element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reinitialize your loop counter to `0` when printing out the numbers :

```
for (j = 0; j < (i + 1); j++) {
    printf("%lf\n", userNum[j]);
}
```

And you need to increment the position in `userNum` that you scan the numbers into :

```
scanf("%lf", &userNum[i]);
```